# how to select attributes of foreign key table with the help of foreign key in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables:

- TableA (A_id, A1, A2, A3)
- TableB (Bid, B1, B2, B3, B4)

I want to access the values the columns of `TableB` while selecting the `TableA`.

Please suggest the select query using which all the values of `TableA` and some of the values of columns in `TableB` can be retrieved.

Note both of the tables are in relationship with foreign key concept.

Comment: Suggest removing `java` and `jdbc` from your tags as this is a straight-up `sql` question.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables together.

Answer (score 0):

You said there is a foreign key relationship, but you did not describe it.  I would expect that TableA has a column Bid or TableB has a column A_id.

Once you have that, you would use a `JOIN` clause in your `SELECT`.